# Setting an initial value in a Django Form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have to setup an initial value in a form and somehow is not working, it is extremely strange as I have exactly the same code in another view, but in this case my approach is not working:

views.py

```
@login_required
def add_lead(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        lead_form = LeadsForm(request.POST)
        if lead_form.is_valid():
            lead_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'You have successfully added a new lead')


            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('add_lead'))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Error updating your Form')

    else:

        user = {"agent":request.user}
        lead_form = LeadsForm(request.POST or None, initial = user)


    return render(request,
                  'account/add_lead.html',
                  {'lead_form': lead_form}
                   )
```

forms.py

```
class LeadsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Leads
        fields = ('project_id','company','agent','point_of_contact','services','expected_licenses',
                  'expected_revenue','country', 'status', 'estimated_closing_date'
                  )
        widgets = {'estimated_closing_date': DateInput(),
                   }
```

Essentially, the agent is the logged user, so I'm passing request.user as a variable, but I have not succeeded, which is very strange because I have that same logic in another form

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: test `user = {"agent":request.user.id}`

Comment: That didn't work, obviously, that gets back the id of the foreign key, but nothing happens... thanks for trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a form with a foreign key you can use `ModelChoiceField`. In your case you can use:

```py
class LeadsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    agent = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Leads
        fields = ('project_id','company','agent','point_of_contact','services','expected_licenses',
                  'expected_revenue','country', 'status', 'estimated_closing_date'
                  )
        widgets = {'estimated_closing_date': DateInput(),
                   }
```

Then you can assign data with user_id in your form initial.

Comment: That worked like a charm, do you mind expanding the explanation on the reason why I had to define the agent in that way?

Comment: because you want to map the value to the model instance and the default form field doesn't do that.